# how to change color for WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK special character

Tags: html, css, unicode

I need a purple heavy check mark, but i only find WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK here:
http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_dingbats.asp
I try to color this with purple, but receive a purple border white heavy check mark. 
How can i fill this check mark all purple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your CHECK MARK inside span tags and apply `color: purple` on this tag

Exemple :

```css
span {
    color: purple;
}
```

```html
<p>I will display <span>&#x2714;<span><p>
```

Comment: I use: <p>I will display <span>&#9989;<span><p>. It can't purple all the check mark, border only with purple, inside still white

Comment: Can you use the `&#x2714;` character or you are stuck with the `&#9989;` ?

Comment: bcoz &#x2714; is not suitable prototype i want. Can i fill &#9989; with purple? Or i will use image